# Facebook shows me events that are nowhere near me

Tags: facebook

I live in Silver Spring, Maryland. Facebook has the idea that I am living in California. Events keep coming up on my timeline happening in California. How can I change Facebook to indicate that I live in Silver Spring and see events happening in Silver Spring?

Answer (score 2):

Besides entering your postal address on your profile, I recommend you use the mobile app with the "Friends Nearby " feature turned on.

This will get a record of your whereabouts into Facebook's algorithms and since that data is correlated to your phone number, it can be considered a strong signal for Facebook's algorithms to determine that you actually live there.

A few check-ins to local places, where friends "established" on the area tag you on their stories and photos, could also be a strong signal, since it's not easy to fake, and somehow "endorses" your whereabouts​ with the social link of previously established and "trustworthy" accounts.

Comment: Have you tried that and found it helpful for that case?

Comment: In fact yes, I have. The complete set of signals that FB uses are, of course, proprietary but they are known to include mobile device location (if granted to their apps) GeoIP databases, EXIF geotags from photos, and location of your friends network. Usually one is friends mostly with people in the same area then people from your hometown, and some outliers. Some nodes on your local network are likely using their apps with location services enables thus providing a weak indicator of location, however that indicator should be considered stronger than user input

Answer (score 1):

Click events.
Click the calendar on the top right.
Click the settings wheel on top right.
Under location click change.
Enter location.
Close app.
When you reopen it the events will be updated

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Most people use app to refer to apps installed  from the App Store or the Play Store. Please be more specific about how to this using a web browser.